# String array for palindrome is adding some extra characters like ⌂

Tags: c

I wanted to do a palindrome but when I do the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char string[100];
    int comparison;
    char again;
    printf("This program will determine whether a word is a Palindrome or not.\n");
    do
    {
start:
        int c;
        printf("Enter the word: \n");
        scanf("%s", string);

        int length = strlen(string);
        char palindrome[length];
        for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
        {
            palindrome[i] = string[length-1-i];
            printf("%c\n", palindrome[i]);
            int validation = isalpha(palindrome[i]);
            if(validation==0)
            {
                printf("Invalid Input! The input must be letters.\n");
                goto jump;
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n", palindrome);
        comparison = strcmp(string,palindrome);
        if(comparison == 0 )
        {
            printf("The word %s is a palindrome.\n", palindrome);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The word %s is not a palindrome.\n", palindrome);

        }
        printf("Do you want to restart the code? Input Y to restart, otherwise any key to terminate  \n" );
        scanf("%s", &again);
        while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF ) { }
    }
    while((again == 'Y') || (again == 'y'));//this will then loop back the code if again is Y, otherwise continues to the next chunk
    printf("Code terminated");
    return 0;


jump://If an invalid input will be placed, the code will jump here
    printf("Do you want to restart the program? Input Y to restart, otherwise any key to terminate  \n" );
    char again2;
    scanf(" %c", &again2);

    if((again2 == 'Y') || (again2 == 'y'))
    {
        goto start;//jumpts to the start on the top
    }
    printf("Code terminated");
    return 0;
}
```

When I input racecar, the code will execute correctly.

But when I input the word civic I get this:

civic
c
i
v
i
c
civic⌂

The word civic⌂ is not a palindrome.

Why is there an additional character ⌂?Thank you

Comment: `char palindrome[length];` --> Hint: where is the space for the _null character_ and where does it get assigned?

Comment: Side note: Your code would be a lot easier to read for yourself and other people if you used consistent [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style). Meanwhile, an edit proposal has been submitted, which will fix this (once it has been accepted).

Comment: sidenote: whenever you feel a need to use `goto` , think about the structure of your program, you are then probably doing something wrong. e.g. use functions instead of having all code in main.

Comment: Always check the return code of `scanf`.

Comment: May want to check some of the other [Palindrome Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55414017/3422102) which may provide further learning in how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add null terminator (`'\0'`) at the end of the string `palindrome`.

For example:

`palindrome[length] = '\0';`

Add the above line after copying all the character from `string` array to `palindrome` array.

If your string is not terminated with `\0`, it might still print the expected output because following your string is a non-printable character in your memory. This is a  bug though, since it might blow up when you might not expect it. Always terminate a string with `'\0'`.

**Note**: As you're adding length number of character in the `palindrome` array, declare the size of `palindrome` array `length +1` ( i.e. `char palindrome[length + 1];`)